# What is the frequency coming out of VCO in GNU Radio?

Tags: gnuradio

[image]

Based on the numbers, can anyone tell me what Sensitivity means in VCO block.

This is what I found so far, but do not understand it.

Sensitivity
units are radians/sec/(input unit)

Comment: hi! this is GNU Radio 3.7, which is a long-dead version of GNU Radio. Please update your GNU Radio, as never versions are much more user-friendly, and have greatly reduced bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=VCO_(complex) explains, not very well, that this is the factor between input and output change in radians per second.

That means that for an input of 1, the output of the VCO rotates by $200\pi$ per second, that is 100 full cycles per second, that is 100 Hz. For an input of 0.5, it rotates half as fast.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Muller, I am trying to simulate an FMCW wave with carrier frequency of 2 GHz and bandwidth of 3 GHz. Which parameter would define the carrier frequncy (starting frequency of the chirp)  in these blocks? Thanks. From the link you provided I assume that is the quiescent frequency.

Comment: I guess the sampling rate is the indication of that, right?

Comment: The sensitivity would define that, as described in my answer. You need to think in "rotation per sample" instead of hertz

Comment: The paper that I got the blocks from says that carrier frequency is 0.2 MHz. How would I get this number from, 200pi sensitivity? Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it.....628.318 K=200Kpi=0.2MHz*pi.

Comment: With the starting voltage of 2V.

Comment: So if sensitivity is 6.28M, that means that carrier frequncy is 1*2pi MHz? On the other paper I am reading  it says the carrier frequency for 6.28M Sensitivity is 1 GHz. Based on your explanaition it should be 1 MHz.   This is the paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7322772

Comment: I don't really know how that other paper applies to your flow graph here. But the math is brutally simple: the sensitivity gives you how much your output phase varies per sample when the input is 1. Output phase change per sample: that's a frequency. I really can't break it down any further – that's really the basics of representing frequency in discrete time.